# How to break a loop without fill all cin variables?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I need a `switch` statement to break an outer `while` loop if someone enters `'q'` in the terminal. It however, doesn't break unless someone satisfies all of the variables for the `cin` statements, or enters another character on a new line.

My code is currently as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main () {
  bool run = true;
  while (run == true) {
 
    int a, b;
    char function;

    std::cout << "Enter the expression: ";
    std::cin >> function >> a >> b;

    if (function == 'q') {
      run = false;
      break;
    }
 
    switch (function) {
      case '+':
        std::cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << a + b << std::endl;
        break;

      case '-':
        std::cout << a << " - " << b << " = " << a - b << std::endl;
        break;

      case '*':
        std::cout << a << " * " << b << " = " << a * b << std::endl;
        break;

      case '/':
        std::cout << a << " / " << b << " = " << a / b << std::endl;
        break;

      default:
        std::cout << "That is not a valid operator!\n";
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use `goto`.

I have several methods of breaking the loop. Including, but not limited to; using an `int` or `bool` for the loop condition, rearranging the variable declarations, and directly breaking the loop.

Comment: If you want to take some action after only reading `function` then the first thing you have to do is change `std::cin >> function >> a >> b;` to `std::cin >> function;`.

Comment: *I unfortunately am not allowed to use goto.* This is not that unfortunate. `goto` can be troublesome to use correctly and it's even harder to prove to reviewers that you've used it correctly. Plus you'll have to re-explain why you used `goto`  to damn near every programmer who looks at the code over the life of the project. Not using `goto`, even in the rare cases where `goto` *is* the right solution for the job, almost always takes less time in the long run.

Comment: When you have a case where you need to `break` from nested loops or from inside a `switch`, consider moving the problem code into a function and returning from that function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```cpp
std::cin >> function >> a >> b;

if (function == 'q') {
    run = false;
    break;
}
```

you could split the extraction from `cin` up into different steps

```cpp
if (not(std::cin >> function) || // 1.
    function == 'q' ||           // 2.
    not(std::cin >> a >> b))     // 3.
{
    break;
}
```

1. Check if extracing to `function` failed. If it didn't, check 2.
2. Check if what was extracted into `function` is `q`. If it isn't, check 3.
3. Check if extraction of the two operands fails.

If any of the conditions are `true`, it will short-circuit the chain of logical ORs and `break` out of the loop, which means that you can exit the loop by typing <kbd>q</kbd>  <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of validating input for `function` you can simply check `function` first and only then continue with the rest:

```
 std::cin >> function;
 if (function == 'q') break;
 std::cin >> a >> b;
```

In general, the easy way to `break` from a nested structure is to `return`. For example to break out of the `while` loop from within the switch you can do the following. Instead of

```
int main() {
    // ...
    while(condition) {
        //...
        switch(function) {
             // ...
             default:
               break; // want to break out of the while
```

Do this:

```
void foo(char function, int a,int b) {
    while(condition) {
        //...
        switch(function) {
             // ...
             default:
               return; // breaks out of the while
        }
}

int main() {
    // ...
    foo(function,a,b);
}
```